# How can .wav files be created on an iPhone or iPad?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, audio

How can `.wav` files be created on an iPhone or iPad? I want to customize the sounds that Outlook for Windows plays when certain events occur and it would be nice if I could make `.wav` files on a mobile device and transfer them back afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

## [Twisted Wave](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/twistedwave-audio-editor/id401438496?mt=8)

This looks like a solid piece of audio editing software. It uses the internal microphone on your iPad to record audio and can export to `.wav` or many other formats.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [WavePad](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pocket-wavepad-hd/id418674227?mt=8)

This also looks like a good app for doing what you want to accomplish. It will export as `.wav`.

[image]